# poor report performance when using with clause

Tags: sql, performance, oracle12c

What is the best way to join humongous table two or more times?
For example In this fictitious example, we have students table, student record who has TUTOR_ID column is a reference to the same table to another student.

What I am trying to accomplish is a report that will find all tutors that share the same students.

So I have built a query like this:
First time to find parent child relationships
Second time to find all tutors that share the same students

I tried to use "with clause" but query performance is really bad
Is there a better approach to take?

```
 WITH STUDENT_TMP_TABLE AS (
select 
TUTORS.STUDENT_IDENTIFIER as TUTOR_STUDENT_IDENTIFIER,
CADETS.STUDENT_IDENTIFIER as CADET_STUDENT_IDENTIFIER
FROM V_STUDENTS_RELATIONS  TUTORS 
INNER JOIN V_STUDENT_RELATIONS  CADETS   ON CADETS.TUTOR_ID = TUTORS.STUDENT_IDENTIFIER AND TUTORS.TUTOR_ID IS NULL
    WHERE -- ? conditions truncated
)
SELECT 
*
FROM STUDENT_TMP_TABLE STUD_TMP1
JOIN STUDENT_TMP_TABLE STUD_TMP2 
    ON STUD_TMP1.TUTOR_STUDENT_IDENTIFIER <> STUD_TMP2.TUTOR_STUDENT_IDENTIFIER 
    AND STUD_TMP1.CADET_STUDENT_IDENTIFIER = STUD_TMP2.CADET_STUDENT_IDENTIFIER;
```

Comment: In your fictitious example, what is the requirement? Note: the requirement is a business problem you must solve; it should be explained in plain English. In particular, "the joins needed" is **never** part of the problem statement. Joins are one way to **solve** a problem, they are not part of the requirement.

Comment: I added some explenation